# how to get rid of unnecessary widget rebuild inside a streambuilder in the ui when using the bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, stream-builder

I am using the bloc pattern in flutter and I want to know what is the  the best way to structure my code to avoid unnecessary rebuild in my StreamBuilder

According to what I learned so far in flutter the the bloc component in the bloc pattern takes a stream of events and maps them to a stream of state which can be then used inside a StreamBuilder to build the UI.

Following this paradigm I made a State Class which includes all the state properties needed in my screen

and also created a Event Classes each one describes a possible event that can happen

my bloc component contains two stream controllers one that listens to the events then maps them to a state accordingly and then adds them to the State Stream

In the Screen Widget I have a StreamBuilder that wraps the Widget that may update and this StreamBuilder gets the bloc State Stream as a Stream

When the user interacts with the Screen UI then the according event will be triggered and added to the Event Stream in the bloc and the cycle goes on and on.

However using this approach I noticed that the StreamBuilder rebuilds all the Widgets in the build method every time an event occurs even if the Widget doesn't need the snapshot.data that came in the State Stream in fact very few widgets will need the actual stream data but all widgets will rebuild.

I gave this some thoughts and research but didn't come with a clear answer. I mean I am following the description of the bloc pattern how the bloc component takes an event and converts it to a state

but when the state model contains many properties then there will be many unnecessary rebuild of the widgets in the StreamBuilder

However in this case I came up with two options

Option 1 :In the bloc component break the State stream to multiple streams each stream for each property of the State

-> problems with this approach :

is that in the Screen UI every group of widgets that use the same property will be clustered together and wrapped with a StreamBuilder in this case we would find many StreamBuilders inside the UI.

Option 2 :Inside the StreamBuilder somehow tell the widget not to rebuild if the passed argument didn't change from the previous one 
but I couldn't find a solution till now how to implement this

*different files are separated with a dashed line

```
class ScreenBloc {
  ScreenState _screenState = ScreenState.initial();

  final _screenStateController = StreamController<ScreenState>();

  StreamSink<ScreenState> get screenStateSink =>
      _screenStateController.sink;

  Stream<ScreenState> get screenStateStream =>
      _screenStateController.stream;

  final _screenEventController = StreamController<ScreenEvent>();

  StreamSink<ScreenEvent> get screenEvenSink =>
      _screenEventController.sink;

  Function get dispatch => screenEvenSink.add;

  ScreenBloc() {
    ScreenStateSink.add(_screenState); //initial data for the stream

    _screenEventController.stream.listen(_mapEventToState);
  }

  void _mapEventToState(ScreenEvent event) {

    //map events to state then add them to the ScreenStateSink
  }

}
------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ScreenState {

  final propertyOne;

  final propertyTwo;

  final propertyThree;


  ScreenState._({this.propertyOne,this.propertyTwo,this.propertyThree});

  factory ScreenState.initial() {
    // initalize
    );
  }
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------

abstract class ScreenEvent {}

class EventOne extends ScreenEvent {}

class EventTwo extends ScreenEvent {}

class EventThree extends ScreenEvent {}


------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Screen

final ScreenBloc _screenBloc = ScreenBloc();

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ScreenState>(
        stream: _screenBloc.screenStateStream,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ScreenState> snapshot) {
                 return Column(
                   children: <Widget>[
                     WidgetOne(snapshot.data.property1),
                     WidgetTwo(snapshot.data.property2),
                     WidgetThree(snapshot.data.property3),
                   ]
                 );
           }
    }
```

Comment: Try to make one bloc maintain one Widget as far as possible, If they are all related, you should plan the responsibility of blocs to keep it clear. In short, make multiple blocs, so you could prevent the unrelated widgets from updating.

Comment: @Tokenyet in my case all widgets are related and i am following the convention of one bloc per screen it would simply solve my problem if I created another streamController in my bloc for that one property or widget that I want to isolate in a separate streamBuilder however I am now looking for a way in my streamSink to not to let duplicate event pass that would solve my problem ! any clues how to do it ?  like how to only let an item to the sink if it is different from the previous one

Comment: I don't think that using bloc that spits out screen states can be be performant because it is hooked up high in the widget hiararchy. I am using custom bloc with multiple streams and provider to provide it. Separate stare can trigger changes lower in hiararchy to avoid unnecessary rebuilds. Advantages of change whole state is that you can recreate history but I don't think it can be made performant

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this use case is that instead of creating one bloc for each screen, create one bloc for each feature needed. Then instead of having the StreamBuilder in the root of `Widget build()`, you can move the StreamBuilder to wrap each widgets that can potentially rebuild due to an update.